# How to have currentMilis and previousMillis like arduino in Lua script

Tags: lua, arduino

I am writing an extremely simple script in Lua using simcom GPU.

It will count how many times a led flashing and return a string correspond to counter number. So far i have using os.clock() to do the job but the result is not as I expected.

```
function counter()
        local t1 = os.clock()   
        while (ReadADC1() > 98) do

            local t2 = os.clock()
            local dt = t2 - t1
            t1 = t2
            local ledValue = ReadADC1()

            if ((ledValue >= OnThreshHold) and (dt < 1)) then -- if led is on for less than 1 second
                ledCounter = ledCounter + 1
                --vmsleep(100)
            elseif ((ReadADC1() < OnThreshHold) and (dt > 2.3)) then-- if led is off for more than 2 second
                ledCounter = 0;
                --vmsleep(100)
            else
                ledCounter = ledCounter
            end

            --print (ledValue,"\r\n")
        end
        print(ledCounter,"\r\n")
        --return ledCounter 
end
```

For this case, if i use this counter() function, it only work if the value from ReadADC() is input for short time then stop. It wont work if adc read continuously flow of data.

In arduino, the solution is extremely easy since you can use currentmillis and previousMillis to determine time pass between flashes. So in lua, do we have anything similar ?

Comment: what is `previousMillis`?

Comment: it's just a time anchor for whatever event happened

Comment: What does `ReadADC1()` actually return and why are you calling it 2 (sometimes 3) times per loop, each time in a different way?

Comment: ReadADC1 will return a decimal value from 50-4096. The only reason I use it differently is because i was testing the module before. The module works fine so i just use it like that.  So ledValue and ReadADC() are the same value